# posting jquery .serializeArray(); output through ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, serializearray

Quick question

If I have serialized a form using jquery's `.serializeArray();` function do I need to do anything to it before I can send it off using jquery's ajax `data:`?

e.g. can I send off

`[{name: inp1, value: 'val1'}, {name: inp2, value: 'val2'}]` as is, or do I need to preprocess it somehow?

and, in php how would I read this?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It would be better here to use [`serialize`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize).  This converts your form's values into a simple string that can be used as the AJAX call's `data` attribute:

```
var myData = $('#yourForm').serialize();
// "inp1=val1&inp2=val2"
$.ajax({
    url: "http://example.com",
    data: myData
});
```

Presuming you send this to PHP using the `GET` method, you can access these values using `$_GET['inp1']` and `$_GET['inp2']`

---

Edit: You can convert an array made by `serializeArray` into a parameter string using [`$.param`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param)

```
var myData = $('#yourForm').serializeArray();
// remove items from myData
$.ajax({
    url: "http://example.com",
    data: $.param(myData) // "inp1=val1&inp2=val2"
});
```

Comment: Post :/

also, I am doing some preprocessing on the returned array (removing the objects that have not been changed from when the form was created), hence why I need the array

Comment: @Hailwood See updated answer. POST variables will be accessible using `$_POST['inp1']` instead, as per normal in PHP.